# Lucene Search returning no results even if it should

Tags: java, search, lucene

I am creating a lucene search application, I used multiple instances of indexWriter with different analyzers and respective indexSearcher, but the search results returned are empty even though I know I have indexed the particular word I'm searching for.

Here is my SearchEngine class constructor

```
this.indexers = new ArrayList<StandardIndexer>();
    this.indexers.add(new StandardIndexer(new StandardAnalyzer()));
    this.indexers.add(new StandardIndexer(new EnglishStemAnalyzer()));
    this.indexers.add(new StandardIndexer(new KeywordAnalyzer()));
    this.indexers.add(new StandardIndexer(new EnglishSynonymAnalyzer()));
    this.indexers.add(new StandardIndexer(new EnglishSynonymStemAnalyzer()));
    this.indexers.add(new StandardIndexer(new EnglishSynonymKeywordAnalyzer()));
    this.searchers = new ArrayList<StandardSearcher>();
    for (StandardIndexer indexer : this.indexers) {
        this.searchers.add(new StandardSearcher(indexer));
    }
```

StandardIndexer and StandardSearcher are my implementations of indexer and searcher, as we can see instance of indexer is used in creation of indexSearcher, hence directory and type of analyzer used is also shared between pairs of indexer and searcher

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about a known bug in unknown code.

So I write in general:

- You have to use "nearly" the same analyzer for indexing and searching. So in the end the token (=word after stemming) in index must match the token in query.
- You must be sure that a commit is finished before your can search an indexed document.
- Be aware that the standard query parser split words at whitespace. You can not search for tokens with whitespace without extra work (escaping the whitespace, search with phrase ..)
- You can use luke to view your index directory https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke

Comment: I have already checked all the points you have mentioned above, using exactly the same analyzer during query creation and search, commit after each write through index writer. I would also like to add that sometimes even after getting results, I do not get all the expected results. For example, I know some string appears in multiple different documents, but the search is returning me only one of the documents.

Comment: Please add code (e.g. based on org.apache.lucene.search.TestBooleanOr) for: 1. "adding two documents with word XY", 2. "searching for XY", 3. finding only one document.